# Why aircraft refrigeration uses a centrifugal compressor in place of reciprocating compressor?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, thermodynamics, refrigeration

Why aircraft refrigeration uses a centrifugal compressor in place of reciprocating compressor and a gas turbine in place of reciprocating expander?

Comment: Nice question. Is that the "universal" case for aircraft refrigeration?

Comment: Fewer moving parts and lower friction losses? What about lighter for same delivery?

Answer (score 3):

I expect it is the capacity , large building AC units are also radial or axial ; smaller units are recips. And as commented , likely there is a weight advantage. I put this question in the Aviation stack .My summation of the general answer is most aircraft AC is supplied by high pressure bleeds from the main engines not conventional AC compressors. The APU powers a conventional radial AC when on the ground, and the main engines are not providing AC.

Answer (score 2):

reciprocating pumps require lubrication, which inevitably injects oil mist into the outflow. This then has to be filtered out before the air enters the cabin. With a centrifugal compressor/blower, there is no oil mist in the airflow and no need for a demisting filter.